# Compute maximum actuator's rate based on the given first-order dynamics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, matlab, control-theory

I have bounded first-order dynamics:

$X_{min} = 0, X_{max} = 2, T=0.01, U = X_{max}$

$\frac{X(s)}{U(s)} = \frac{1}{Ts+1}$

I need to compute:

$\dot{X}_{max}$

So far I've end up with Matlab/Octave code:

```
T_sim = 1; % simulation time (sec)
dt = 0.005; % time step
N_step = floor(T_sim/dt); % number of steps
time = 0; % current time (sec)
time_plot = zeros(1, N_step);
x_plot = zeros(1, N_step);
x_c_plot = zeros(1, N_step);

x_min = 0;
x_max = 2;

x_rate_max = 0;

x_prev = x_min; % previous value is minimum
u = x_max; % commanded value is maximum (step input)

T = 0.01; % time constant

for i = 1:N_step

  % first-order dynamics in Laplace form: X(s)/U(s) = 1/(T*s + 1)
  % discretized system (ZoH):
  % x(k+1) = exp(dt*(-1/T))*x(k) + (1 - exp(dt*(-1/T))) * u(k)
  alpha = exp(-dt / T); 
  x = alpha * x_prev + (1 - alpha) * u;

  x_rate = (x - x_prev)/dt; % current rate
  x_rate_max = max(x_rate, x_rate_max); % maximum rate

  x_plot(i) = x;
  x_c_plot(i) = u;
  x_prev = x;

  time_plot(i) = time;
  time = time + dt;
end

plot(time_plot, x_c_plot, ";x_c;");
hold on;
plot(time_plot, x_plot, ";x;");
hold on;
grid on;
```

Which gives me `x_rate_max = 157.39` and the step response is:

[image]

So the questions:

1. Is this result correct?
2. If it is then how to solve the opposite task and to compute $T$ based on the given $\dot{X}_{max}$?

Comment: How can you bound the input rate? Are you sure you are not looking to bound $\dot{X}$? Why would you need a simulation to compute this?

Comment: 1. I bound U_min and U_max, not the U_rate_max. 2. I don't have other ideas.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. The dynamics are $\dot{x} = {1 \over T}(-x +u)$ so if you are trying to bound $\dot{x}$ you need a bound on the initial state and $u$.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more consistent with control theory notation. My goal is to compute the maximum rate of the output based on a given transfer function and step input. Is it possible anyway, or the maximum rate of output is the quantity independent from the dynamics?

Comment: Both answers are correct, but the answer given by @SampleTime is more useful since it mentions discretization. I recalculated all time constants and max rates for all actuators in my model and it seems that if discretization is taken into account the model gives smoother trajectory. Which I expected to get.

Comment: It is not at all clear where discrete time features in the above.

Comment: I use dt=0.005 across my model and it seems x_rate_max = 157.387 gives more smooth trajectory than theoretically computed x_rate_max = 200. Theoretical solution is very useful too of course.

Comment: @Elia I am not sure what you mean with that and how you measered the smoothness of your trajectory and how a lower dt can affect that. Maybe you should add to the question what you are trying to achieve because that sounds a lot like an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Maybe you are talking about adding rate limitations to the control loop (just a guess)?

Comment: My goal is to add dynamics of the actuators to the nonlinear control allocation problem. It requires rate limitations, and these limits have to be consistent with modelled actuator dynamics. I plot actuator outputs on a graph and they look less noisy if u_rate_max is computed with the same dt as model has.

Comment: @Elia Maybe you should post this as a new question, because that sounds quite different from your question here. At least its difficult to tell, because too much information is missing.

Comment: @SampleTime Thanks for the suggestion but I think its not necessary. For the clarification, I have already solved my goal with 'perfect' actuators that have maximum rate 1e6 so this basically means they have no dynamics. To make these actuators more realistic I have added first order dynamics, and posted this question. Two answers that were provided were good enough to solve my task completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a first order transfer function

$$
G(s) = \frac{K}{T s + 1}
$$

In time domain with a step input of height $\bar{U} = U_{max} - U_{min}$ that is:

$y(t) = \bar{U}\, K \, (1 - e^{-t/T})$

So you can take the derivative with respect to $t$:

$$
y'(t) =  \frac{\bar{U}\, K}{T} e^{-t/T}
$$

The derivative has a maximal value at $t = 0$ (directly at the step) because the $e^{-t/T}$ is monotone decreasing from $1$ to $0$ asymptotically (of course we assume $T > 0$ so that $G$ is stable).

So the maximum rate is

$$
y_{max}' = \frac{\bar{U}\, K}{T} 
$$

so it only depends on $T$ and $\bar{U}\, K$, which is the maximum value your actuator can produce. For your second question, you can of course solve this for $T$:

$$
T = \frac{\bar{U}\, K}{y_{max}'} 
$$

---

In your case, $K = 1$, $T = 0.01$, $U_{min} = 0$, $U_{max} = 2$, so you have

$$
y_{max}' = \frac{(2 - 0) \times 1}{0.01} = 200.
$$

The difference from that value to your code comes from the discretization. Here are some values you get for different sample times `dt` with your simulation:

```
dt         x_rate_max
---------------------
0.005      157.3877
0.0025     176.9594
0.001      190.3252
0.0001     199.0033
0.00001    199.9000
0.000001   199.9900
```

So you can see that the estimated value approaches the theoretical value of $200$ we just computed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am missing something entirely, but this seems very straightforward.

The dynamics are $\dot{x} = { 1\over T} (-x+u)$ and hence
$\sup_t \{ |\dot{x}(t) | x \in [0,2], u=2\} = \sup_t \{ { 1\over T} |u-x| | x \in [0,2], u=2\} = {2 \over T} = 200$.